# How do I force Webrat to fill_in an disabled field?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webrat

I have a text area that becomes enabled (via JS) when the user checks a checkbox near it.
However, webrat does not execute the JS and spits out a `Webrat::DisabledFieldError`.
Can I force webrat to fill the field, or somehow overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing javascript behavior, you should use some tool like [Selenium](https://github.com/brynary/webrat/wiki/Selenium).

Comment: I am not testing javascript behavior. The JS is purely aesthetic , I don't care if it works or not.

Comment: If you're not, then you should have a non-javascript fallback. AFAIK you can't force Webrat to fill a disabled form.